# Rails has_many with finder_sql and name_scope in combination return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, named-scope

For example lets say you have:

```
       class Model < AR::Base 
         has_many :somethings, :finder_sql => "SELECT * FROM somethings"
       end

       class Something < AR::Base
         named_scope :valuable {...code...}
       end

       # Assume you have one model but 0 somethings:  
       # Model.first.somethings          # => [] Good!
       # Model.first.somethings.valuable # => nil Bad! Should return [] !!!
```

This only occurs when you have finder_sql in has_many relationship. In other cases it works as expected.

Is this normal behavior of Rails 2.3.14?

Comment: why do you even have the finder_sql specified?  You are just duplicating the existing ar has_many query lookup code

Comment: Nope, I don't. You see I dont have WHERE condition at all.

Comment: then I guess I'm completely lost as to why you have your models setup how you do.  If you want the whole collection of Something objects, you shouldnt declare it as a has_many on Model - as that inplies it is a 1-to-many relation ship.  Why not just use your own class method that returns an AR::Relation object with the Something objects you are lookingfor?

Comment: @Filip: you should either accept the answer or explain why it's not good. Appreciate other users' efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, if you specify finder_sql, then you will not be able to append scopes. that's because finder_sql is for situations that do not fit the normal activeRecord paradigm.  That being said, the way you have this constructed is incorrect. you should not need to store a select * with no filters in a relationship like that. the purpose of a relationship is to apply a filter to the other model.  so, the way you have it Model.find(params[:id]).somethings is exactly the same as calling Something.all . the scope will work for you in the latter case because .all can be scoped.